# Android Viewpager with partial views on fragments

Tags: android, android-fragments

I am trying to use Viewpager in a fragment. The Viewpager has 4 fragments in it with different Imageviews. When scrolling through the Viewpager I would like partial views of the other fragments (their imageviews) to be seen, so the user knows he can choose. It should look something like this:
[Scrolling with partial views](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LnETA.png)
I am a beginner and this might not be the right approach, so please if so, point me in the right direction.

My Viewpager:

```
public class MyAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {
public static int int_items = 4;

public MyAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
    super(fm);
}

@Override
public Fragment getItem(int position) {
    switch (position) {
        case 0:
            return Fragmentone.newInstance();
        case 1:
            return Fragmenttwo.newInstance();
        case 2:
            return Fragmentthree.newInstance();
        case 3:
            return Fragmentfour.newInstance();
    }
    return null;
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return int_items;
}
```

The fragment with the Viewpager:

```
public class MainHostFragment extends Fragment implements ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener {
private static ViewPager mViewPager;

public static MainHostFragment newInstance() {
    return new MainHostFragment();
}


@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main_host, container, false);
    mViewPager = (ViewPager) rootView.findViewById(R.id.myViewPager);
    mViewPager.addOnPageChangeListener(this);
    mViewPager.setAdapter(new ViewPagerAdapterMassage(getChildFragmentManager()));
    return rootView;
}

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {

}

@Override
public void onPageScrolled(int position, float positionOffset, int positionOffsetPixels) {

}

@Override
public void onPageSelected(int position) {

}

@Override
public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int state) {

}
```

Comment: Have you thought about a RecyclerView with a horizontal LinearLayoutManager?

Comment: Exactly. This behaviour can be easily achieved by `RecyclerView` with horizontal scroll.

Comment: Nope, haven't thought about it. :( 
But, would you care to elaborate the steps on how it should be done?
Thanks,
Jay

Comment: Best thing to do is use recycler view, but if you want to keep using viewpager set negative margins to it